# UIAccessibility on subview of UIWINDOW

Tags: uiaccessibility

Hi have added Viewcontroller view into UIWINDOWS as below

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:self.myviewcontroller.view];
```

But now for myviewcontroller view UIAccessibility is not working. Its getting whatever backside of that window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured solution,
 we should add subview on topmost window.

```
        UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    if (!window)
        window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
    [[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:self.myviewController.view];
```